# What is the most efficient way to add content to a position on a string with php

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have a string `localhost/uploads/images/photo.jpg`, I just want to simply rename it to `localhost/upload/images/photo_thumb.jpg`, keeping in mind that is a dynamic data and am just using it to simply what I want to achieve. I have tried to use the `strpos()` function to get the position of the '.' then use it for something(this where I got lost), then another thought came to me use implode. I will appreciate if some can help me figure this out thanks.

```
<?php
function get_google_image_url($type, $id, $column = 'image', $multi = "",$thumb=''){
  if($multi ==''){
    //check if there is thumbnail add _thumb before extention
    if($thumb != ''){
      $l= $this->db->get_where($type,array($type.'_id'=>$id));
      $n = $l->num_rows();
      if($n >0){
        $value = $l->row()->$column;
        $position = strripos($value,'.');
        return $l->row()->$column;
      }
    }else{
      $l= $this->db->get_where($type,array($type.'_id'=>$id));
      $n = $l->num_rows();
      if($n >0){
        /$value = $l->row()->$column
          $position = strripos($value,'.');
        //this where i got stucked
        //return $l->row()->$column;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

that's the function am trying to implement it in, but what I want to achieve is what I stated above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the best way here is to use `pathinfo`

something like that should work

```
$path_parts = pathinfo('localhost/uploads/images/photo.jpg');
$strNewName = $path_parts['dirname'].'/photo_thumb.jpg';
echo $strNewName;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it by using regex and [preg_replace](https://3v4l.org/jR4in):

```
$string="localhost/uploads/images/photo_thumb.jpg";
$replacement="$1/$2_thumb.$3";
$pattern= '/([\w+\/]*)(?=\/)\/([\w]+(?<!_thumb))\.(\w+)/i';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

code you can run it [here](https://3v4l.org/jR4in)

`$1 = matching until last /`

`$2 = name of the file`

`$3 = file extension`

feel free to improve the regex pattern if needed.

Comment: the reg is somehow new to me what of we don't know the number of occurence. i mean the pattern please  share more light

Comment: I don't understand your problem, does my fix work for you or not? what do you mean by the number of occurences? do you need it in a `for` loop or what? If you want to learn more about regex start here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html because this is not the goal of the question